# Facebook Authentication : Getting "operation is not valid due to current state of the object" in WP8

Tags: facebook, authentication, windows-phone-8

Hi I have trying a facebook authentication for my app. I used the below code to authenticate :

```
 private async void OnClickCommand()
        {
            if (!App.isAuthenticated)
            {
                App.isAuthenticated = true;
                await Authenticate();
            }
        }
        private async Task Authenticate()
        {
            string message = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                _facebookSession = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
                App.AccessToken = _facebookSession.AccessToken;
                App.FacebookId = _facebookSession.FacebookId;

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login failed! Exception details: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Earlier this code was working perfectly. But now i tried to use the same code , its displaying a warning page like shown in fig#1 , and when i click the back button its show the exception in a message box (as in Fig#2). 
The output shows the following exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Facebook.Client.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

And the stack trace is

> at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.d__1b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.<LoginAsync>d__f.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at ResKueMe.MainPageViewModel.d__4.MoveNext()

Fig#1
[image: Warning]

Fig#2

[image: Exception]

I also tried to delete my app on developers.facebook.com/apps and tried to add a new app, but the problem still persists!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK for .NET - Security Warning Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149284/facebook-sdk-for-net-security-warning-issue)

Comment: that's also not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also face this issue so many times and found that this Error comes up due to Phone Incorrect Date Time   and once i correct the DateTime of my phone this issue get fixed, try once

Comment: Yes..it may be because of that.. I got that error resolved without any changes after some days :)