# facebook loginbutton on wp8 issues

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook c# sdk in my windows phone 8 app. When I click the login button of the facebook Controls using the loginbutton control it ask for username and password.
After entering the credentials it shows me
"security warning please treat the url above as you would your password and do not share it with any..." page and then I cannot do anything.
It is always showing me the same page.

Also the sandbox mode for the facebook app whose id I am using in wp8 app is disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK for .NET - Security Warning Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149284/facebook-sdk-for-net-security-warning-issue)

Comment: I am using loginbutton control to login to facebook. The solution provided in the link will work if you are using your own login button to login.

Answer (score 0):

I [filed a bug report to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/441946462581973) today on this issue, posted one workaround to the [Facebook SDK for .NET - Security Warning Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467301/2897961) thread.

The short answer is that authorization is broken and adds a question mark after the redirect_uri link, and FacebookSDK.NET does direct comparison between actual and expected Uri, and fails.